# Как интерпретировать html код отправленный на страницу из flask приложения?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

Имеется html код такого вида [image: пример html]

нужно его интерпретировать на странице. Как мне это сделать? на данный момент код отображается на странице так же как на скриншоте.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение на ссайте https://pythonru.com/uroki/7-osnovy-shablonizatora-jinja
данная проблема решается с помощью

```
{% autoescape false %}
    {{ переменная содержащая html }}
{% endautoescape %}
```